# ASP.NET SqlDataSource update and create FK reference

Tags: asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

The short version:

I have a grid view bound to a data source which has a SelectCommand with a left join in it because the FK can be null. On Update I want to create a record in the FK table if the FK is null and then update the parent table with the new records ID. Is this possible to do with just SqlDataSources?

The detailed version:

I have two tables: Company and Address. The column Company.AddressId can be null. On my ascx page I am using a SqlDataSource to select a left join of company and address and a GridView to display the results. By having my UpdateCommand and DeleteCommand of the SqlDataSource execute two statements separated by a semi-colon I am able to use the GridView's Edit and Delete functionality to update both table simultaneously.

The problem I have is when the Company.AddressId is null. What I need to have happen is have the data source create a record in the Address table and then update the Company table with the new Address.ID then proceed with the update as usual. I would like to do this with just data sources if possible for consistency/simplicity sake. Is it possible to have my data source do this, or perhaps add a second data source to the page to handle some of this?

Once I have that working I can probably figure out how to make it work with the InsertCommand as well but if you are on a roll and have an answer for how to make that fly as well feel free to provide it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> execute two statements separated by a
>   semi-colon

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible to do both an INSERT and UPDATE in two statements with SqlDataSource just like you are doing here.

However, just so you know, if you have a lot of traffic or users using the application at the same time, you can run into concurrently issues where one user does something that affects another user and unexpected results can cascade and mess up your data. In general, for things like what you are doing - INSERT and UPDATE involving primary or foreign keys, usually SQL TRANSACTIONs are used. But, you must execute them as SQL stored procedures (or functions), on your SQL database. You are still able to call them from your SqlDataSource however by simply telling it that you are calling a stored procedure.